# How can I customize the text editor or color tag parts of my code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, color-scheme, ide-customization

How do I customize, extend the text editor, or color tag parts of my code?

1. I would like Visual Studio to color code parts of my code. Can I use `#region` and give it a color?
2. Is there any way to make the background between two parentheses have a different color? (I want each code "block" to have its own color.)

I've looked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885121.aspx) for some insight, but they all are implemented based "on what you select". All I want is to have the text editor "render" the text in a different way based on some rules.

Comment: Visual Studio has *syntax highlighting* built in. I suppose that's not what you're looking for? You want to highlight an entire block of text in a single color? I don't believe that's possible. Why in the *world* would that ever be helpful?

Comment: Well... writing code can become very cryptic very fast. Using the latest c# 3.0 and 4.0 features makes it even worse. I was looking intro drawing vector graphics to bound text objects.

Comment: Have you looked in the extension library?

There is an extension called 'VS10x Method Block Highlighter' that does a bit of what you are asking for. It's not a stretch to think there are others.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such feature, but there is something quite close to what you are looking for in ReSharper. A setting called "Highlight matching delimiters". Looks like this in use:
[image: Resharper matching delimiter highlighting]

I wanted tell you this because 
1) You might be interested in resharper and 
2) resharper is able to do the highlighting so maybe someone can make an add-in or something to add this kind of feature. Maybe you? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything exactly like what you're asking for, but the VS10x Code Map extention might help: http://www.axtools.com/products-vs2010-extensions.php

It will give you a nice overview of the code on the side, and make navigation somewhat easier.

The download button on the right lets you download a trial version from the Visual Studio Gallery at msdn.microsoft.com. I think you can also find it directly from the extentions view in VS2010.